# pandas dataframe where clause with dot versus brackets column selection

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a regular DataFrame with a string type (object) column. When I try to filter on the column using the equivalent of a WHERE clause, I get a `KeyError` when I use the dot notation. When in bracket notation, all is well.

I am referring to these instructions:

```
df[df.colA == 'blah']
df[df['colA'] == 'blah']
```

The first gives the equivalent of

> KeyError: False

Not posting an example as I cannot reproduce the issue on a bespoke DataFrame built for the purpose of illustration: when I do, both notations yield the same result.

Asking then if there is a difference in the two and why.

Comment: I strongly advise you get into the habit of using square brackets rather than dot notation to access your columns, the dot notation accesses a df's attributes and will look up first class attributes and methods first, and then columns if they exist. It is very error-prone and will lead to strange errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dot notation is just a convenient shortcut for accessing things vs. the standard brackets. Notably, they don't work when the column name is something like `sum` that is already a DataFrame method. My bet would be that the column name in your real example is running into that issue, and so it works fine with the bracket selection but is otherwise testing whether a method is equal to `'blah'`.

Quick example below:

```
In [67]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape(5,2), columns=["number", "sum"])

In [68]: df
Out[68]:
   number  sum
0       0    1
1       2    3
2       4    5
3       6    7
4       8    9

In [69]: df.number == 0
Out[69]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
Name: number, dtype: bool

In [70]: df.sum == 0
Out[70]: False

In [71]: df['sum'] == 0
Out[71]:
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
Name: sum, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Spot on, the column is called `size`.