# Pandas: update column values from another column if criteria

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a DataFrame:

```
   A B

1: 0 1
2: 0 0 
3: 1 1
4: 0 1
5: 1 0
```

I want to update each item *column A* of the DataFrame with values of *column B* if value from *column A* equals 0.

DataFrame I want to get:

```
   A B

1: 1 1
2: 0 0 
3: 1 1
4: 1 1
5: 1 0
```

I've already tried this code

`df['A'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: x if df['A'] == 0 else df['A'])`

It raise an error :`The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: Not sure this is a duplicate.  The linked duplicate is about adding a new column based on another column.  This is about updating an existing column (and is easier to find via google).  @sailestim My apologies that this was marked as a duplicate.  Please keep the questions coming.

Comment: Answers below use both dot and bracket notation, some references suggest brackets are better:     https://www.dataschool.io/pandas-dot-notation-vs-brackets/        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030013/pandas-dataframe-where-clause-with-dot-versus-brackets-column-selection

Answer (score 38):

```
df['A'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['B'] if x['A']==0 else x['A'], axis=1)
```

Output

```
    A  B
1:  1  1
2:  0  0
3:  1  1
4:  1  1
5:  1  0
```

Answer (score 15):

Use `where`

```
In [348]: df.A = np.where(df.A.eq(0), df.B, df.A)

In [349]: df
Out[349]:
    A  B
1:  1  1
2:  0  0
3:  1  1
4:  1  1
5:  1  0
```

Comment: Which solution is more efficient by time, yours or by Rusabh?

Answer (score 10):

You can perform this by using a mask:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['A'] = [0,0,1,0,1]
df['B'] = [1,0,1,1,0]
mask = (df.A == 0)
df.loc[mask,'A'] = df.loc[mask,'B']

    A   B
0   1   1
1   0   0
2   1   1
3   1   1
4   1   0
```

EDIT:
Ok this is actually a unefficient solution:

```
%timeit df.loc[mask,'A'] = df.loc[mask,'B']
%timeit df.apply(lambda x: x['B'] if x['A']==0 else x['A'], axis=1)
%timeit np.where(df.A.eq(0), df.B, df.A)

5.52 ms ± 556 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
1.27 ms ± 167 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
796 µs ± 89.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

So thanks to zero for this efficient solution with np.where!

Comment: This is actually the most efficient as it uses only 100 loops.