# Update column value based on value in other column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am referencing to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51787247/pandas-update-column-values-from-another-column-if-criteria). I want to update a column value based on value in another column.

```
name_list = ['C', 'E']
df = pd.DataFrame([('A', 'buy'),
                  ('B', 'sell'),
                  ('C', 'hold'),
                  ('D', 'loan'),
                  ('E', 'hold')], columns=['name', 'action'])
```

```
    name     action
1    A          buy
2    B          sell           
3    C          hold
4    D          loan
5    E          hold
```

Here is two tries I came up with:

```
df['action'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'removed' if x['name'] in name_list else df['action'])
df['action'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'removed' if x['name'].isin(name_list) else df['action'])
```

Both tries above gives this error `KeyError: 'name'`
The expected output is

```
    name     action
1    A          buy
2    B          sell           
3    C          removed
4    D          loan
5    E          removed
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use loc:

```
df.loc[df['name'].isin(name_list),'action']='removed'
```

OR

For you current method pass `axis=1` but using `apply()` is slow for this simple case:

```
df['action'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'removed' if x['name'] in name_list else x['action'],axis=1)
```

output of `df`:

```
    name    action
0   A       buy
1   B       sell
2   C       removed
3   D       loan
4   E       removed
```

**Note:** you can also use `np.where()`:
`np.where(df['name'].isin(name_list),'removed',df['action'])`

Answer (score 1):

Use [df.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)-

```
df['action'] = df['action'].where(~df['name'].isin(name_list), 'removed')
```

**Output**

```
0        buy
1       sell
2    removed
3       loan
4    removed
Name: action, dtype: object
```